# How do I implement expression searching with Spring Data Solr?

Tags: java, spring, solr, lucene, nutch

I started using Spring Data Solr a few days ago and I found it quite nice even though there just a few examples and the tools still seems very immature in terms of features.

For example, suppose I've a query like

> what's the meaning of "easy peasy lemon squeezy"?

Currently what I'm doing is simply defining the methods for query like we normally do with Spring Data (to query for example a SQL database). For example, if I've a field in my document called `content`, I could have a query method of a repository as follows:

```
@Highlight(prefix = "<mark>", postfix = "</mark>")
List<MyDocument> findByContentIgnoreCase(List<String> contents, Pageable p);
```

this works quite fine for the purpose of just finding all documents by content, which (I must be honest) I'm not 100% sure how it's implemented. I know Lucene uses a VSM, but I would not know more than that.

If I've a more specific query, like the one above, how would you implement it using Spring Data Solr, possibly with highlighting results, which is a very nice feature (of Solr?)?

Comment: This may be helpful...  https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/solr/spring-data-solr-tutorial-query-methods/